# Ruby: Compare if array contains other array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, include, compare

how can i compare if an array of strings contains a smaller array of strings in Ruby?

e.g.

```
a=["1","2","3","4","5"]
b=["2","3"]
```

now i want to check if a contains b and get true/false

Thanks.

Comment: you can check by `(a & b) == b`, it will return boolean value `true` / `false`

Comment: @GaganGami nope, this is not correct; `&` squeezes duplicates resulting in weird `[1, 1] & [1, 1] == [1, 1] #⇒ false` because surprisingly `[1, 1] & [1, 1] == [1]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa : noted, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common approach would be to

```
(b - a).empty?
```

It has issues with unique elements, though. To detect whether `a` includes *all* elements from `b`, one should:

```
a_copy = a.dup
b.all? { |e| a_copy.delete e }
# or
b.all?(&a_copy.method(:delete))
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with `b.all? { |x| a.include(x) }`

Comment: @EnginTopuzoglu once again, it won’t work if arrays might contain duplicates.

Comment: I see, thanks, they dont contain duplicates but they might, so i changed it to your code, still working